# Angular-js datepicker flowing out of the form window

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, datepicker

I have added a date-picker in my webpage but when i click on the calendar icon the date-picker is flowing out of the window, it looks odd to see. tried to reduce width, its not working. I have added the CSS file also.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      .my-datepicker .form-control {
    height: 10px;
    width:10;
    padding: 11px;
}

.my-datepicker .btn {
    padding: 1px 2px;
}


  .dropdown-menu table {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <strong>Status!</strong> {{ObjStatus}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
            <div class="form-group" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="margin:1em" ng-click="editObj()" value="Edit" ng-show="Complete">Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="margin:1em" ng-click="requestReview()" value="Submit" ng-hide="Review">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right"style="margin:1em" ng-click="saveAllObj()" value="Save" ng-hide="Review">Save</button>                         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="menuTab1" class="btn btn-default  btn-primary active" ng-click="tab1()" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <div class="hidden-xs">Focus on Customer</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="menuTab2" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tab2()" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <div class="hidden-xs">Focus on Growth</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="menuTab3" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tab3()" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <div class="hidden-xs">Focus on Performance</div>
                    </button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">

                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <!-- Quarter - 1 table -->
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="form-group" ng-hide="true">                                            
                                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="saveObj()" value="Save">
                                        </div>
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                            <thead> 
                                                <tr ng-hide="Review">
                                                    <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAllObj" ng-click="checkAllObj()" /></th>
                                                    <th>Individual Objectives</th>
                                                    <th>Measurable Outcomes</th>
                                                    <th>Priority %</th>
                                                    <th>Key Activities</th>
                                                    <th>Completed By</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr ng-hide="!Review">                                                   
                                                    <th>Individual Objectives</th>
                                                    <th>Measurable Outcomes</th>
                                                    <th>Priority %</th>
                                                    <th>Key Activities</th>
                                                    <th>Completed By</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="objectivesDetail in objectivesDetails" ng-hide="Review">
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="objectivesDetail.selected" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Individualid" ng-model="objectivesDetail.Individual" ></textarea>                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"  id="Measurableid" ng-model="objectivesDetail.Measurable" ></textarea>                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="Priorityid" ng-model="objectivesDetail.Priority" ></textarea>
                                                    </td>    
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="Keyid" ng-model="objectivesDetail.Key" ></textarea>
                                                    </td>                                                  
                                                    <td>
                                                        <p class="input-group my-datepicker">
                                                            <input type="text" size="1" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="objectivesDetail.Completed" is-open="objectivesDetail.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
                                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,objectivesDetail)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>                                               
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="objectivesDetail in objectivesDetails" ng-hide="!Review">                                                    
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetail.Individual}}                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetail.Measurable}}                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetail.Priority}}                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetail.Key}}                                                       
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetail.Completed | date :  "dd-MMM-yyyy"}}                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <div class="form-group" ng-hide="Review">
                                            <button ng-hide="!objectivesDetails.length" style="margin:1em" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="removeObj()" value="Remove">Remove</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" style="margin:1em" ng-click="addNewObj(objectivesDetails)" value="Add New" ng-disabled="objectivesDetails.length>employeeCount">Add New</button>                                           
                                        </div>                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <!-- Quarter - 1 table -->
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="form-group" ng-hide="true">                                            
                                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="saveObjGro()" value="Save">
                                        </div>
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                            <thead> 
                                                <tr ng-hide="Review">
                                                    <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAllObjGro" ng-click="checkAllObjGro()" /></th>
                                                    <th>Individual Objectives</th>
                                                    <th>Measurable Outcomes</th>
                                                    <th>Priority %</th>
                                                    <th>Key Activities</th>
                                                    <th>Completed By</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr ng-hide="!Review">
                                                    <th>Individual Objectives</th>
                                                    <th>Measurable Outcomes</th>
                                                    <th>Priority %</th>
                                                    <th>Key Activities</th>
                                                    <th>Completed By</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="objectivesDetailGro in objectivesGroDetails" ng-hide="Review">
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="objectivesDetailGro.selected" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="IndividualGroid" ng-model="objectivesDetailGro.IndividualGro"></textarea>                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="MeasurableGroid" ng-model="objectivesDetailGro.MeasurableGro"></textarea>                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="PriorityGroid" ng-model="objectivesDetailGro.PriorityGro"></textarea>
                                                    </td>    
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="KeyGroid" ng-model="objectivesDetailGro.KeyGro"></textarea>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <p class="input-group my-datepicker">
                                                            <input type="text" size="1" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="objectivesDetailGro.CompletedGro" is-open="objectivesDetailGro.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" />
                                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,objectivesDetailGro)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>                                                                                                       
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="objectivesDetailGro in objectivesGroDetails" ng-hide="!Review">                                                    
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailGro.IndividualGro}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailGro.MeasurableGro}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailGro.PriorityGro}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailGro.KeyGro}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailGro.CompletedGro | date :  "dd-MMM-yyyy"}}
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <div class="form-group" ng-hide="Review">
                                            <button ng-hide="!objectivesGroDetails.length" type="button" style="margin:1em" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="removeObjGro()" value="Remove">Remove</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" style="margin:1em" ng-click="addNewObjGro(objectivesGroDetails)" value="Add New" ng-disabled="objectivesGroDetails.length>employeeCount">Add New</button>                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab3">
            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <!-- Quarter - 1 table -->
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="form-group" ng-hide="true">                                            
                                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="saveObjPre()" value="Save">
                                        </div>
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                            <thead> 
                                                <tr ng-hide="Review">
                                                    <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAllObjPre" ng-click="checkAllObjPre()" /></th>
                                                    <th>Individual Objectives</th>
                                                    <th>Measurable Outcomes</th>
                                                    <th>Priority %</th>
                                                    <th>Key Activities</th>
                                                    <th>Completed By</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr ng-hide="!Review">
                                                    <th>Individual Objectives</th>
                                                    <th>Measurable Outcomes</th>
                                                    <th>Priority %</th>
                                                    <th>Key Activities</th>
                                                    <th>Completed By</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="objectivesDetailPer in objectivesPreDetails" ng-hide="Review">    
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="objectivesDetailPer.selected" />
                                                    </td>                                               
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="IndividualPreid" ng-model="objectivesDetailPer.IndividualPre"></textarea>                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="MeasurablePreid" ng-model="objectivesDetailPer.MeasurablePre"></textarea>                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" cols="1" id="PriorityPreid" ng-model="objectivesDetailPer.PriorityPre"></textarea>
                                                    </td>    
                                                    <td>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="KeyPreid" ng-model="objectivesDetailPer.KeyPre"></textarea>
                                                    </td>                                                   
                                                    <td>
                                                        <p class="input-group my-datepicker">
                                                            <input type="text" size="1" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="objectivesDetailPer.CompletedPre" is-open="objectivesDetailPer.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" />
                                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,objectivesDetailPer)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>                                                       
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="objectivesDetailPer in objectivesPreDetails" ng-hide="!Review">                                                    
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailPer.IndividualPre}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailPer.MeasurablePre}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailPer.PriorityPre}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailPer.KeyPre}}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {{objectivesDetailPer.CompletedPre | date :  "dd-MMM-yyyy"}}
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <div class="form-group" ng-hide="Review">
                                            <button ng-hide="!objectivesPreDetails.length" style="margin:1em" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="removeObjPre()" value="Remove">Remove</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" style="margin:1em" ng-click="addNewObjPre(objectivesPreDetails)" value="Add New" ng-disabled="objectivesPreDetails.length>employeeCount">Add New</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
      </div>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This you tried

```
    .form-control {
    height: 10px;
    width:10px;
    padding: 11px;
}
      .my-datepicker{
    height: 10px;
    width:auto; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it effects all the fields and datepicker did not work

Comment: How is datepicker different from other fields?